# 2-way synchronization of text structure?

Tags: javascript, regex, data-structures

I know the title is a bit confusing, but I have no idea to describe precisely what I mean.
I have a minimal demo below:

```
class A{
    name: string;
    age: number;

    toString(){
        return `
        My name is: ${this.name},
        My age is: ${this.age}
        `
    }

    fromTextToData(text: string){
        //Do something, regex or something?
        this.name = ...;
        this.age = ...;
    }
}

main(){
    let a = new A();
    a.name = "Name 1";
    a.age = 20;
    let text = a.toString();
    var revert = a.fromTextToData(text);
}
```

The best way I can think about it is using `Regex expression`, but if the data is large or something the structure is duplicated to its others, I think it's not really a good solution.
The second solution I can think of is using a data structure such as `JSON` or `XML`.
But I still want some suggestions from you.

Comment: Using a serialisation format such as JSON or XML is definitely the way to go. Is there any reason you're trying to avoid them?

Answer (score 2):

That is possible, but I would first change a few things in your code:

- Allow the constructor to take arguments for initialising its properties:

  ```
      constructor(name, age) {
          this.name = name;
          this.age = age;
      }
  ```
- Make the reversing method a **static** method that returns a **new** instance of `A` instead of overwriting the properties of an existing instance. I would also just call it `fromText`
- To better ensure that both `toString` and `fromText` rely on the same string format, define a kind of template as a static property of the `A` class. This template could take different forms. Here I will propose an array:

  ```
  static template = ["\nMy name is: ", "\nMy age is: ", "\n"]
  ```

  So the idea is that the dynamic parts get inserted between those strings. On the other hand, the reverse action can identify these strings and extract what is in between them with `(.*?)` as part of the regular expression.

```js
class A {
    static template = ["\nMy name is: ", "\nMy age is: ", "\n"]
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    toString(){
        return [this.name, this.age]
               .map((data, i) => A.template[i] + data)
               .concat(A.template.slice(2))
               .join("");
    }
    static fromText(text) {
        const regex = RegExp(A.template.join("(.*?)"));
        // Get the match, and extract with slice the captured groups
        return new A(...text.match(regex).slice(1));
    }
}

function main() {
    const a = new A("Name 1", 20);
    const text = a.toString();
    const revert = A.fromText(text);
    console.log(revert);
}

main();
```

### Remark

If the goal is to serialise and deserialise instances, then it is better not to rely on such human-readable phrases as string representations, but use a format proven for that purpose, like JSON.

So then it would go like this:

```js
class A {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    toString() {
        return `
        My name is: ${this.name},
        My age is: ${this.age}
        `
    }
    static fromJSON(json) {
        return Object.assign(Object.create(this.prototype), JSON.parse(json));
    }
}

function main() {
    const a = new A("Name 1", 20);
    const json = JSON.stringify(a);
    const revert = A.fromJSON(json);
    console.log(revert);
}

main();
```